# Javascript generated table - How to update other cells in a row when a number input value in this row changes

Tags: javascript, html

I am facing a problem for this day I am creating a **pop-up cart** with a table, I create an array with

> ID | NAME | QUANTITY | PRICE

then I generate the table from this array with javascript.
My problem is I want to be able to update the price and the total when I change the quantity for a specific item line (= quantity in the table row). This should work for all generated table rows.

**This is my javascript code:**

```
var cartCount = 0;
var Total = 0;
var id = 1;

var labels = ['Name', 'Quantity', 'Price'];
var items;
var cartElement = document.getElementById('cartDisplay');
var counterElement = document.getElementById('counterDisplay');

function cartClick(name, quantity, price) {
  const x = {
    id: id,
    name: name,
    quantity: quantity,
    price: price
  };

  if (Obj.some(e => e.name === x.name)) {
    console.log('already there');
  } else {
    Obj.push(x);
    cartCount = cartCount + 1;
    Total = Total + x.price;

    id = id +1;

    buildTable(labels, Obj, document.getElementById('modalBODY'));
    items = Obj;
    console.log(items);
  }

  CheckCart(cartCount);
  console.log(cartCount);
}

function CheckCart(counter) { 
  if (counter > 0) {
    cartElement.style.display = "block";
    counterElement.innerHTML = counter;
  } else {
    cartElement.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function buildTable(labels, objects, container) {
  container.innerHTML = '';

  var table = document.createElement('table');
  // class table
  table.classList.add("cartTable");

  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  var theadTr = document.createElement('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    var theadTh = document.createElement('th');
    theadTh.classList.add("cartTh");
    theadTh.setAttribute("colSpan", "2");
    theadTh.style.padding = '12px';
    theadTh.innerHTML = labels[i];
    theadTr.appendChild(theadTh);
  }
  thead.appendChild(theadTr);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  for (j = 0; j < objects.length; j++) {
    var tbodyTr = document.createElement('tr');
    for (k = 0; k < labels.length; k++) {
      var tbodyTd = document.createElement('td');
      tbodyTd.classList.add("cartTd");
      tbodyTd.setAttribute("colSpan", "2");
      tbodyTd.style.padding = '12px';
      if (labels[k] === "Quantity") {
        var qinput = document.createElement('input');
        qinput.setAttribute("type", "number");
        qinput.setAttribute("min", "0");
        qinput.setAttribute("max", "10");
        qinput.setAttribute("id", "quantityInput");
        qinput.setAttribute("value", objects[j][labels[k].toLowerCase()]);
        tbodyTd.appendChild(qinput);
      } else {
      tbodyTd.innerHTML = objects[j][labels[k].toLowerCase()];
    }
    tbodyTr.appendChild(tbodyTd);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tbodyTr);
  }

  table.appendChild(tbody);

  var tfoot = document.createElement('tfoot');
  var footTr = document.createElement('tr');
  var footTh = document.createElement('th');

  var footTd = document.createElement('td');
  footTd.setAttribute("id", "totalElement")

  tbodyTd.setAttribute("colSpan", "3");
  footTh.setAttribute("colSpan", "4");

  footTd.innerHTML = Total;
  footTh.innerHTML = 'TOTAL';
  footTd.classList.add("cartTd");
  footTd.classList.add("footerTable");
  footTh.classList.add("cartTh");

  footTr.appendChild(footTh);
  footTr.appendChild(footTd);
  tfoot.appendChild(footTr);

  table.appendChild(tfoot);

  container.appendChild(table);

  var beforeText = document.createElement("p");
  beforeText.style.marginTop = '5px';
  beforeText.innerHTML = "Requests";
  container.appendChild(beforeText);

  var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.style.width = '100%';
  input.style.padding = '6px';
  input.setAttribute("placeholder", "No onion, no tomato...");
  container.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Please host it on jsFiddle and share the link for ease

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem by creating a rowid and when the user clicks into the row I check for changes. Here the main idea

```
tableRow.setAttribute("id", "row" + idTable + "_" + tableRow.rowIndex); // for easy handling and selecting rows

tableRow.addEventListener("click", function(){ ... here check for what ever change});
```

You could also go for a specific change in just one cell, so attach the eventlistener to each quantity cell and read the new value, validate and update other fields then

```
qinput.addEventListener("change", function(){ ... here check for what ever the change triggers });
```

EDIT fortheOP:
A generic example for adding an event listener to a tablerow this marks the selected table line red (class table-danger) and removes the colour from allother previous selected lines:

```
tableRow.addEventListener("click", function(){
    tRowData = [];
    if(this.classList.contains("table-danger")) {
        this.classList.remove("table-danger");
        return;
    } else {
        var nodeParent = this.parentNode;
        var trows= nodeParent.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for(var i = 0; i < trows.length;i++) {
            trows[i].classList.remove("table-danger");
        }
        this.classList.add("table-danger");

        var cells = this.getElementsByTagName("td");
        for ( i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            tRowData.push(cells[i].innerHTML); // e.g.: Here you could place your update routine
        }

        tRowData.push(this.getAttribute("id"));
        tRowData.push(this.rowIndex);

        return tRowData;
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply can you please provide an example.

Comment: Just add the line from above (qinput.addEventListener... ) and filll in your check code. I'm sorry not to write complete code as an unpaid service, perhaps somebody else will do. An example from my code base above in Edit.

Comment: If the solution fits please mark as solvedfor others to know